# I am getting a reduce/reduce conflict in the following bison grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

The following grammar matches a struct with field declarations in bison. Can someone point out where the reduce reduce conflict is ?

Struct Ex:
struct mystruct { int var;}

```
%start start

    %%
    start      : program             { $$ = parser::root->adopt($1); }
               ;
    program    : program structdef   { $$ = $1->adopt ($2); }
               |
               ;
    structdef  : TOK_STRUCT TOK_IDENT '{' fielddecls '}' {
               destroy($3);  destroy($5);
               $$ = $1->adopt($2, $4);}
               ;
    fielddecls : fielddecl {$$ = $1;}
               | fielddecl fielddecls {$$ = $1->adopt($2);}
               | {$$ = nullptr;}
               ;
    fielddecl  : basetype TOK_IDENT ';' {$$ = $1->adopt($2);}
               ;
    basetype   : TOK_VOID    {$$ = $1;}
               | TOK_INT     {$$ = $1;}
               | TOK_STRING  {$$ = $1;}
               | TOK_IDENT   {$$ = $1;}
               ;

    %%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the rule

```
fielddecls : fielddecl {$$ = $1;}
           | fielddecl fielddecls {$$ = $1->adopt($2);}
           | {$$ = nullptr;}
           ;
```

which is ambiguous -- you have a recusive rule and TWO base cases, so any sequence of 1 or more fielddecl can be recognized either way.  You need to have only one base case:

```
fielddecls : fielddecl fielddecls {$$ = $1->adopt($2);}
           | {$$ = nullptr;}
           ;
```

will match any sequence of 0 or more fielddecl.